# How to convert give you Matlab figures in Latex a cleaner look

Tags: tikz-pgf, matlab, matlab2tikz

I am trying to import my Matlab graphs into LaTex. I already know how to do it. However, the graphs have poor quality and are unproportioned. How do you get those Mablab figures to appear "HD" in your Latex document.  I've tried matlab2tikz. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "poor quality", can you share one example? Why don't you export to EPS and use that?

Comment: The method I normally use for vector images is `saveas(gcf,'name','.eps2c')`. It is a `eps` file, `2` is a better version and `c` for color. We need an example to better understand your issue. If you want a non vector image, `png` often looks better than `jpeg`.

Comment: Like my actual code? It's a report so it's alot. But as you can see from the pics, the graphs aren't too great.

Comment: @Missael Save them as EPS and use that.

Comment: @Missael Any progress?